# failed to create base_local_planner after changing global planner

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, carrot-planner, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to do the comparison of global planning methods available in navigation stack.
When I change global planner of move_base from navfn to carrot_planner I`m getting following error:

```
Failed to create the base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS planner, are you sure it is properly registered and that the containing library is built? Exception: MultiLibraryClassLoader: Could not create class of type base_local_planner::TrajectoryPlannerROS
```

`[move_base-2] process has died`

In order to change planning method I modified the launch file by including this line

```
<param name="base_global_planner" value="carrot_planner/CarrotPlanner"/>
```

Why is this happening?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81051/failed-to-create-base_local_planner-after-changing-global-planner/) by [babtu](https://answers.ros.org/users/6866/babtu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-09-19

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-09-20**:
Precisely what parameter did you change?

**Comment by [babtu](https://answers.ros.org/users/6866/babtu/) on 2013-09-25**:
I wanted to change global planner of move_base and i followed instructions included in this post http://answers.ros.org/question/39347/how-to-change-global-planner-of-move_base/?answer=39357#post-id-39357

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-09-25**:
Go back a step. Does your launch file work if you don't include that line?

**Comment by [babtu](https://answers.ros.org/users/6866/babtu/) on 2013-09-25**:
Yes, works like a charm. It also works when i set value to "navfn/NavfnROS" (default planner).

**Comment by [fmder](https://answers.ros.org/users/662/fmder/) on 2013-10-04**:
I have the same problem. Works great by setting navfn/NavfnROS but dies when using carrot_planner/CarrotPlanner. I'm using ros-groovy.

**Comment by [BP](https://answers.ros.org/users/10951/bp/) on 2014-03-17**:
I have the same problem. Have you solved it?

**Comment by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) on 2014-10-14**:
Same problem here. Carrot Planner works fine with dwa_local_planner, but I get the same error when trying to use it with base_local_planner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A) Make sure all your planners are built. B) Try this launch file http://pastebin.com/FDxzwxaD (add your own map instead of some_package)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2013-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-06-13**:
how do you build the planner?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-06-13**:
[I meant compile](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/BuildingPackages)